# How to render three elements of each time? React

Tags: reactjs

I will want to render only three elements of my array `numbers` each time.

The each time that i will click em `next` to change the numbers.

e.g:
On Screen: 123, i clicked in button, will appear, 456 and onwards.

MyCode:

```js
class Contador extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      elementsPerPage:3,
      currentPage:0,
      numbers:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    };

    this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this);
  }
  
  nextPage () {
   this.setState({ currentPage: this.state.currentPage + 1 });
    console.log(this.state.currentPage)  
  }
  
  elementsOnScreen () {
    this.state.numbers.map((number)=>
      <li>{number}</li>)
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Elements: {this.elementsOnScreen} </h1>
      <h1>Current Page: {this.state.currentPage}</h1>
      <button onClick={this.nextPage}> next </button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
<Contador/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
elementsOnScreen () {
  const { currentPage, numbers, elementsPerPage } = this.state;
  return numbers
    .slice(currentPage*elementsPerPage, currentPage*elementsPerPage + elementsPerPage + 1)
    .map(number => (<li>{number}</li>));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use slice method to extract three elements from `this.state.numbers` and map over them using map function.

```
elementsOnScreen () {
 const { currentPage, numbers, elementsPerPage } = this.state;
 return numbers
  .slice(currentPage*elementsPerPage, currentPage*elementsPerPage + elementsPerPage)
  .map(number => (<li>{number}</li>));
}
```

also, when you are rendering a function inside jsx, you have to call the function and not pass its value

```
<h1>Elements: {this.elementsOnScreen()} </h1>
```

`this.elementsOnScreen` will pass the function, it will not run the function. To run the function and return its values you have to do `this.elementsOnScreen()`.